# Unable to get sum to calculate

Tags: javascript

I am trying to work out a payment amount for a project.

I have very little experience with javascript so I am still learning.  I end up with NaN when I try and calculate this.

```
echo 'Hello ' .  htmlspecialchars($_GET["your-name"]);
    echo '<br>Your email address is ' .  htmlspecialchars($_GET["your-email"]);
    echo '<br>Your mobile number is ' .  htmlspecialchars($_GET["text-904"]);
    echo '<br>Your landline number is ' .  htmlspecialchars($_GET["text-834"]);
    echo '<br>Your total debt is £' .  htmlspecialchars($_GET["text-706"]);
    echo '<br>Your monthly income is £' .  htmlspecialchars($_GET["text-134"]);
    echo '<br>Your outgoings are £' .  htmlspecialchars($_GET["text-175"]) . ' per month';      
    echo '<p id="amount">' .  htmlspecialchars($_GET["text-706"]) . '</p>';
    echo '<p id="payment"></p>';


<script>
num1 = document.getElementById("amount").value;
var x = 10;
var y = 5000;
var d = 48;
var e = num1 / x;
var f = e + y;
var z = f / d;
document.getElementById("payment").innerHTML = z;
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("amount").value` returns a string (even if the value is a number, its type is a string, which can't be used for calculations), so you need to convert it to a number, i.e.  `parseInt(document.getElementById("amount").value)` ... or `parseFloat()`

Comment: I tried the paraseInt example as you said but still end up with NaN.

Comment: Then the code is executed before the page been loaded, or the input does not have a value, or the id is wrong ... add `console.log(num1);` after the `num1 = document.getElementById("amount").value;` line and check it has a value

Comment: Open your browser console and check for errors...

Comment: The information is collected on a form and passed to another page.
This is the results page where the payment amount is shown.

Comment: So you are trying to `getElementById()` from another page? If so then you cannot do that. To run `getElementById()` it must be on the page you're running that script.

Comment: I did that and shows NAN before the posted information.

Comment: but the script is in the footer.

Comment: Can you show how the source code looks after the php executed / after page load? https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://pastebin.com/ Also why aren't you running the calculation in PHP?  since the information is coming from PHP I can't understand why you want to run javascript to do something that can be done in PHP as it's already being used...

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I will keep trying.

Comment: I took your advice and used php, works fine.